# Getting Segmentation Fault on running hyperledger/explorer in docker container

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-explorer

I am getting segmentation fault and docker exited with code 139 on running hyperledger-explorer docker image.

docker-compose file for creating explorer-db

```
version: "2.1"

volumes:
  data:
  walletstore:
  pgadmin_4:
    external: true

networks:
  mynetwork.com:
    external:
      name: bikeblockchain_network

services:
  explorerdb.mynetwork.com:
    image: hyperledger/explorer-db:V1.0.0
    container_name: explorerdb.mynetwork.com
    hostname: explorerdb.mynetwork.com
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 54320:5432
    environment:
      - DATABASE_DATABASE=fabricexplorer
      - DATABASE_USERNAME=hppoc
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=password
    healthcheck:
      test: "pg_isready -h localhost -p 5432 -q -U postgres"
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      mynetwork.com:
        aliases:
          - postgresdb

  pgadmin:
      image: dpage/pgadmin4
      restart: always
      environment: 
        PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: user@domain.com
        PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: SuperSecret
        PGADMIN_CONFIG_ENHANCED_COOKIE_PROTECTION: "True"
        # PGADMIN_CONFIG_LOGIN_BANNER: "Authorized Users Only!"
        PGADMIN_CONFIG_CONSOLE_LOG_LEVEL: 10
      volumes:
        - "pgadmin_4:/var/lib/pgadmin"
      ports:
        - 8080:80
      networks:
        - mynetwork.com
```

docker-compose-explorer file

```
version: "2.1"

volumes:
  data:
  walletstore:
    external: true
  pgadmin_4:
    external: true

networks:
  mynetwork.com:
    external:
      name: bikeblockchain_network

services:
  explorer.mynetwork.com:
    image: hyperledger/explorer:V1.0.0
    container_name: explorer.mynetwork.com
    hostname: explorer.mynetwork.com
    # restart: always
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
      #Host is VM IP address with ports exposed for postgres. No issues here
      - DATABASE_PORT=54320
      - DATABASE_DATABASE=fabricexplorer
      - DATABASE_USERNAME=hppoc
      - DATABASE_PASSWD=password
      - LOG_LEVEL_APP=debug
      - LOG_LEVEL_DB=debug
      - LOG_LEVEL_CONSOLE=info
      # - LOG_CONSOLE_STDOUT=true
      - DISCOVERY_AS_LOCALHOST=false
    volumes:
      - ./config.json:/opt/explorer/app/platform/fabric/config.json
      - ./connection-profile:/opt/explorer/app/platform/fabric/connection-profile
      - ./examples/net1/crypto:/tmp/crypto
      - walletstore:/opt/wallet
      - ./crypto-config/:/etc/data
    command: sh -c "node /opt/explorer/main.js && tail -f /dev/null"
    ports:
      - 6060:6060
    networks:
      - mynetwork.com
```

error

```
Attaching to explorer.mynetwork.com
explorer.mynetwork.com    | Segmentation fault
explorer.mynetwork.com exited with code 139
```

Postgres is working fine. Docker is updated to the latest version.
Fabric network being used is generated inside IBM Blockchain VS Code extension.

Answer (score 0):

I too face the same problem with docker images but I was success on manual `start.sh` but not on the docker image. After some exploration, i came to know  this is due to some architecture build related and there seem to be a segmentation fault issue in the latest `v1.0.0` container image.

This get fixed it on the latest master branch, but not yet released it on Docker Hub.

Please build Explorer container image by yourself by using `build_docker_image.sh` on your local for the time being.

*from hlf forum*

Answer (score 0):

Okay!! So I did some testings and found that if, the Docker is set to Run on Windows Login, Explorer will throw error of segmentation fault, but if, I manually start Docker after windows login, it works well. Strange !!